# Why does my java method act differently when made to run multiple times?

Tags: java, methods

When this method `checkUserInput()` below is called just once (when user's first entry is a number from 1 to 3) it works fine.

However, when the method is called more than once, it prints out the correct error message as it is supposed to and reruns "Enter". However, when user then types in a number from 1 to 3 at this point, the program runs differently: it doesn't recognize numbers as numbers, or it doesn't convert the numbers by deducting one, or it gets to the end and runs again.

What could be the cause?

```java
static List checkUserInput() {
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    int g = 0, h = 0;
    boolean numeric = true;
    boolean numera = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0, a = 0, r = 0;
    String m = scanner.next();

    try {
        yAxis = Integer.parseInt(m);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        numeric = false; //
    }

    if (!numeric) {
        System.out.println(" numbers only!"); //exclude letters
        checkUserInput();
    }

    String n = scanner.next();

    try {
        xAxis = Integer.parseInt(n);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        numera = false; //
    }

    if (!numera) {
        System.out.println(" numbers only!"); //exclude letters
        checkUserInput();
    } else if (xAxis < 1 || xAxis > 3 || yAxis < 1 || yAxis > 3) { 
        System.out.println("1 to 3 only!");
        checkUserInput();
    } else {
        //inputs that pass all tests can proceed
        //assign array indices to respective coordinates
        g = yAxis - 1;
        h = xAxis - 1;
    }

    cords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    cords.add(g);
    cords.add(h);
    return cords;
}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you learn how to debug your programs, it will help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> `checkUserInput();`

You seem to think this resets execution back to the start. No, it doesn't - java methods are reentrant. It will run another 'copy' of your checkUserInput method and once it returns, continues running. So, if the first `scanner.next()` call returns a non-numeric value, the 'numbers only!' error handling block will run **the entire method** again, and once the entire method has finished, continues at `String n = scanner.next()`, causing a jumbled mess.

It'll also mean that if you mis-enter input often enough your code will explode with a StackOverflowError.

I strongly suggest you do not call your own method. Use (do/)while loops instead.

Comment: I tried using a "do while" loop instead, the program is still not acting as expected. It doesn't obey the conditional statements in the "do{}" and subsequent output varies with what the first input is.

Comment: Then you have an all-new, entirely original new bug. Programming is hard, and all that. I suggest you ask a new SO question. Make sure to paste all your code.